# UITextView strange behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitextview, ios7

Okay I'm lost here.

So have this `UIViewController` we can call it `viewController1` where I add a new editable `UITextView` for every click on an add button.

I then use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` so you can drag them where ever you want. This works just fine. Now I want to go to `viewController2`: `[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];` but when I press the back button to return to `viewController1` the first `UITextView` that was created in `viewController1` has changed. It's not gone but the text property inside the textview has moved.

**This just happens for the first instance of UITextView** that I create, any ideas here would be appreciated.
Here's my method for creating the text:

```
-(void)addTextFieldToScreen
{
    UITextView *textView = [[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 80, 140, 120)];
    textView.text = @"TEXT";
    textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    textView.textColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    textView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AmericanTypewriter" size:30];
    textView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *panRecognizer = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveText:)];
    panRecognizer.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    panRecognizer.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
    panRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [textView addGestureRecognizer:panRecognizer];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];
}
```

And here's my method for making my textView dragable:

```
-(void)moveText:(id)sender {

    [[[(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender view] layer] removeAllAnimations];

    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender view]];
    CGPoint translatedPoint = [(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender translationInView:self.view];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        firstX = [[sender view] center].x;
        firstY = [[sender view] center].y;

    }

    translatedPoint = CGPointMake(firstX+translatedPoint.x, firstY+translatedPoint.y);

    [[sender view] setCenter:translatedPoint];

    if([(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        CGFloat finalX = translatedPoint.x + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].x);
        CGFloat finalY = translatedPoint.y + (.35*[(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender velocityInView:self.view].y);
        CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
        CGFloat workingWidth = screenRect.size.width - 40;
        CGFloat workingHeight = screenRect.size.height - 80;

        if(finalX < 50) {

            finalX = 50;
        }

        else if(finalX > workingWidth ) {

            finalX = workingWidth;
        }

        if(finalY < 80) {

            finalY = 80;
        }

        else if(finalY > workingHeight) {

            finalY = workingHeight;
        }


        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveLinear];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.20];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**

Okay here's whats going on, I add two textviews with content "TEXT"  with the "add text" button in the right corner in viewController1:

[image]

And then when I come back from viewController2 to viewController1 this is what I see:

[image]

As you can see it's only the left textView instance text property that change position, and this is the first one I'm adding.

Comment: What do you meany by "It's not gone but the text inside the view has moved." ?

Comment: I mean the text property to the textview, I editied my question

Comment: The text property inside textview cant move on its own. Give a background color to your UITextView and you see this is not the case.

Comment: I did that and believe it or not it has moved inside the textview. So wierd..

Comment: Post an image of that phenomenon here. Please post it after you have changed the background color of UITextView otherwise its difficult to see.

Comment: Absolutely, I will be home at my computer in a few hours, I'll post it then. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I updated the question with some images

Comment: Try this - no pan GR, no animations.  When you add the text view, say "if this is the first text view added, place it at 10,10.  if this is the second text view place it at 200, 200".  Push and pop the second vc.  Has the text moved?  Unlikely (imo).  I think the problem lies in either the pan gr or animation or both.  Once we've established that, we know where to look to fix.

Comment: I removed the pan, animation and inserting two textviews with different frames and it's still there.. Could this be a ios7 bug perhaps?